# Commenting on your own posts should be a privilege

Tags: feature-request, comments, privileges

Commenting on other people's posts (*comment everywhere*) is a privilege requiring 50 reputation. But commenting on your own posts is not a privilege at all, users can do so from the start (? Or it is a very easy privilege).

I often seen this scenario:

1. A new user posts a question that is unclear or incomplete.
2. A veteran posts a comment asking for clarification or more information.
3. The new user replies with the requested information *in a comment*.
4. The question itself remains unclear or incomplete.

We should be encouraging new users to edit their questions to provide the requested clarification or missing information, rather than using the comment feature.

I suggest that commenting on even your own posts should be a privilege, requiring a reputation of 15(?)

Comment: I think that we should implement a message such as `Wait!  Are you trying to add more to your question? Use the [edit](link to edit) button to do so!` or something like that.

Comment: @JeffreyLin Already done. Users leaving a comment on their question are told: "Use comments to reply to other users or notify them of changes. If you are adding new information, edit your post instead of commenting." This is written in the same text box they are looking at...

Comment: @CareBear So then isn't this already good enough? Apparently not I guess.

Answer (score 7):

I don't agree. If someone asks for clarification, new user will every time edit his post. Even if it doesn't need to be edited. Or will write answers. Or will ask a new question because of not knowing how to respond. On the main site, because posting on meta requires 5 repz.

If new user put a clarification in comments, a veteran can include it in the question. Not vice versa, or it will be a bit illogical and will make too many revs.